# OraOLEDB ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, etl, oraoledb

I have the following SQL in Oracle:

```
 SELECT 
 CE.ENCNTR_ID                                              AS CernerEncounterID
,TO_DATE(S.ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')    AS NoteStartDateUTC
,S.AUTHOR_ID                                               AS CernerPersonID 
,S.STORY_COMPLETION_STATUS_CD
,CE.EVENT_CD                                               AS CernerNoteTypeCD
,TO_DATE(CE.VALID_FROM_DT_TM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')      AS VALID_FROM_DT_TM
,TO_DATE(CE.VALID_UNTIL_DT_TM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')     AS VALID_UNTIL_DT_TM 
,CE2.EVENT_CD                                              AS EVENT_CD  
,TO_DATE(CE2.VALID_FROM_DT_TM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')     AS AuthVerifiedValidFromDate 
,TO_DATE(CE2.EVENT_END_DT_TM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')      AS AuthVerifiedEventEndDate  
,TO_DATE(CE2.PERFORMED_DT_TM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')      AS AuthVerifiedPerformedDate
,TO_DATE(CE2.VERIFIED_DT_TM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')       AS AuthVerifiedDate
,TO_DATE(CE2.CLINSIG_UPDT_DT_TM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')   AS AuthVerifiedClinSigUpdateDate
,CE2.AUTHENTIC_FLAG       AS AuthVerifiedStatus
,CE.ENTRY_MODE_CD         AS CernerEntryModeDisplayCD
,S.TITLE
,STORY_TYPE_CD
,S.EVENT_ID
,S.ACTIVE_STATUS_CD
,TO_DATE(S.ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')    AS IncrementalDateTimeFlag

FROM 
Table01  S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Table02  CE  
ON 
S.EVENT_ID = CE.EVENT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
Table03  CE2  
ON 
S.EVENT_ID = CE2.EVENT_ID 
AND 
CE2.RESULT_STATUS_CD = 25
WHERE 
S.ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM >= TO_DATE('2019-06-20 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

It runs without any issues in Oracle SQL Developer.

> Executing in SSIS generates the following error: An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description:
>   "ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format".

I have been seeking for info for a while, dead end so far.
Could you please kindly advice?

Comment: What are the data types of columns ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM, VALID_FROM_DT_TM, etc.?